# jQuery Post() Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've read a few articles on here about people having issues with jQuery post in IE 9 and 8. I've followed the reccomendatinos and still can't fix the issue.

The code is a simple video tracker, and for some reason, does not work in any version of IE.

Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        var account = "parts_survey"; // Account name, no spaces
        jQuery.post("http://mydomain.com/tracking/vt.php", { title: url, video_url: href, account: account } );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol."

Comment: No network traffic ? Or problem once on the server ?

Comment: @Ghommey so if it was a local file on the same server it should work?

Comment: On need to write `jQuery`. Use `$` instead.

Comment: Any activity in the console? Is there an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: does not look if location is defined?

Comment: Try `$.post("/tracking/vt.php", { title: url, video_url: href, account: account } );`

Comment: @WesleyMurch I do not see any errors in the console.

Comment: @Jako: Try logging the response and params. Next try hardcoding the params. Just basic debugging.

Comment: @Ghommey, that fixed the issue. But what about for domains I want to track outside of where that vt.php file is hosted. Is there any other workarounds for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol."

Try `$.post("/tracking/vt.php", { title: url, video_url: href, account: account } );`

For cross domain requests have a look at `$.getJSON`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works